# Fetching the duplicate data in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

> I'm trying to fetch the duplicate data from a mysql table.
>   My table contains 4 columns.. In that 3 are having duplicate rows and 1 is having partial duplicate rows.

So now I would like to fetch the four columns with count in the result set.

For example:-

Table Name is **Address** and 
Column Names are **Zipcode**, **HouseNumber**, **HouseNumberExt**, **BuildingColour**.

So the Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt column contains the duplicate data and BuildingColour column may or may not contain the duplicate data. Now i need a query to fetch the data as below.

**Table**

---

```
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     Zipcode        |     HouseNumber |  HouseNumberExt |   BuildingColour|
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600056         |        32       |        A        |    White        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600056         |        32       |        A        |    White        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Blue         |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Black        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Purple       |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600058         |        34       |        C        |    Red          |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600059         |        35       |        D        |    Pink         |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600059         |        35       |        D        |    Yellow       |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     600059         |        35       |        D        |    Pink         |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

**Result Set**

```
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     Zipcode        |     HouseNumber |  HouseNumberExt |   BuildingColour|   Count (*) |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600056         |        32       |        A        |    White        |    2        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Blue         |    1        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Black        |    1        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600057         |        33       |        B        |    Purple       |    1        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600059         |        35       |        D        |    Pink         |    2        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     600059         |        35       |        D        |    Yellow       |    1        |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------|
```

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: I tried with this query but couldn't get all the duplicates.

SELECT BuildingColour, Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt, COUNT(*)
FROM address
GROUP BY BuildingColour, Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Zipcode, a.HouseNumber, a.HouseNumberExt, a.BuildingColour, COUNT(*)
FROM address a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt, COUNT(*)
    FROM address ad
    GROUP BY Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t ON a.Zipcode = t.Zipcode AND a.HouseNumber = t.HouseNumber AND z.HouseNumberExt = t.HouseNumberExt
GROUP BY Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt, BuildingColour
```

Comment: No Jitendra. This doesn't give the result set what i want. It'll check for the duplicate BuildingColour values also. So the condition fail here.

Comment: Can you show me like which record in output is not matching? So we can check what's going wrong here.

Comment: Jitendra, this query is fetching all the rows in table. Is there any way i can fetch only the duplicate rows.

Comment: @Suryateja, see my updated answer, does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Jitendra, This is exactly what I'm looking for.. Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help. You can definitely improve this query, like right now join is based on which should be included, you can select which should not be included from inner query and do a left join and pick only which are not matched.

Answer (score -1):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt, BuildingColour, count(*)
from address
group by Zipcode, HouseNumber, HouseNumberExt, BuildingColour;
```

If you wanted only duplicate results, you would add `having count(*) > 1`.

Comment: No Gordon. This doesn't give the result set what i want. It'll check for the duplicate Building colour values also. So the condition fail here.

Comment: @Suryateja . . . How does this not do what you want?  It should produce exactly the results you are asking for.

Comment: Gordon, this query is fetching all the rows in table. Is there any way i can fetch only the duplicate rows.

Comment: @Suryateja . . . The results in your question have both duplicated and singletons.